# Java conventions for accessible data. (Public accessors & Getters/Naming)

Tags: java, naming-conventions, getter-setter

Through the Java API you see numerous occurrences of conflicting naming and practices which are really confusing to me.

**For example:**

The [String](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/String.java) class has a private variable (Integer) by the name of `count` which keeps track of the size of the string, however this is returned by a getter by the name of `length()`.

If you move over to any type of arrays, instead of having a getter method for length, they just pass the variable through with a public accessor, and it can be obtained through `arrayInstance.length`.

Moving back to the String class we have the `String#getBytes()` method which is a getter, similar to the `length()` getter, however performs slightly more logic to get and return the value.

To me, personally, creating a getter with the prefix of `get` seems redundant, for example I rather type `GamePacket#data()` versus `GamePacket#getData()` however I feel like there may be a deeper meaning behind this naming instead of just inconsistency.

Also, why doesn't the `Array[]` use a getter for `length`?

Would anybody be kind enough to shed some light on this for me?

Comment: An array won't be re-sized. The `length` is `final` and harmless.`

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils - Good to note, missed that, +1.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Getters (and setters) come from the Java Bean specification. The reasons to use them are multiple:

- most Java developers expect accessors to be named like that
- an API respecting these conventions is easier to discover. For example, in my IDE, I'll often press `get` <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Space</kbd> to discover all the information available in an object.
- many APIs and frameworks rely on these conventions to work: the JSP EL, MVC frameworks populating beans from request parameters, JPA, dependency injection frameworks like Spring, etc.

You *usually* name the getter the same way as the private variable that holds the information, but what matters is encapsulation and the public API, so nothing prevents you from computing a value in a getter, or to name the private field a different way.

Comment: I'm sorry, perhaps I'm not reading your answer properly, so is it correct convention to use `getXXX()` apposed to `XXX()` or does it really not matter?

Comment: Yes, it's a convention that most developers respect, especially if there is a chance for their class to be used in an environment relying on these conventions.

Answer (score 1):

This is not going to be a full answer, as a real answer would probably require interviewing the original developers of Java or otherwise researching historical records. But here are a few notes:

- As you were told in the comments, the `length` field of an array is `final`, therefore it cannot be set.
- Both arrays and the `String` class were designed in the earliest versions of Java, before the conventions for getters and setters were settled upon. The `get...` `is...` and `set...` conventions have only really been settled upon at the introduction of JavaBeans. Changing the API would make old code stop working, and so the old names persist.
- In general (e.g. classes which are not JavaBeans), there is actually no rule that says the getter and setter methods have to reflect the name of any particular field in the class. The whole idea of accessor methods is that they hide implementation, so whatever is behind them can be a field, a combination of fields, or something else altogether.

Answer (score 0):

Naming conventions appear to vary throughout the Java codebase, but one early standard was the JavaBeans naming convention; this basically formed an nomenclature solution to Java's lack of true properties.

Object/primitive getters had the form getXXX(), except for booleans, which had the preferred form isXXX().  Setters were always in the form setXXX().

From this single point, millions of lines of reflective code were written.

This convention pre-dated annotations, which would have been a trade-off between increased intent and increased verbosity when writing something like this pseudo-ish code

```
@Setter
void data(Data data) {
    this.data = data;
};

@Getter
Data data() {
    return data;
};
```