# When do I create a getter method without "get" in its name?

Tags: java

The following question has been bothering me for a long time and I couldn't find any information on the naming conventions.

There is methods like:

```
java.util.Collection.size();
```

This method is actually a getter for the size of a Collection, yet it doesn't begin with "get" unlike regular getter methods.

So what are the naming conventions for these types of methods?

Comment: Fun fact is that due to how `get` was not added to that method, there are hacks needed to call it from JSP files if I remember correctly.

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29843508/java-conventions-for-accessible-data-public-accessors-getters-naming

Comment: @Perdomoff the question isn't about whether you should use getters or not, but when to use a getter like `value()` and when `getValue()`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Collection.size()` is not a typical getter as it is not a simple return of a field- it is the size of a collection, for this reason you don't have `setSize()`, since this is not a field you set- this is a 'calculated' value.

You can think of it this way- getter and setters usually go together, in order to encapsulate a field- if you can't do `setX()`, than it's not a typical getter/setter.

But this is only a matter of convention, there are people who believe in always using it without the words get or set.

Comment: `StringBuilder.setLength()` :)

Comment: @bayou.io `StringBuilder` is not a `Collection`.

Answer (score 4):

There is no real 'rule' for this. Sometimes classes give you values by functions like `size()` or `length()`. Others will give it back by `get...()`.

From my experience, lengths are usually got from `size()` or `length()` (like arrays), for other variables it goes by `get...()` (like in android - `getHeight()`).

You can say it because getters go with setters, if there is no setter to size - there wouldn't be a getter.

Answer (score 1):

These methods come from the early versions of Java, the very first versions there were of Java 1 (v1.02, etc). 
In this example, the Collections framework wasn't introduced yet. It was introduced only in Java 1.2. By then, we only had java.util.Vector and java.util.Hashtable.
After the introduction of the collections framework, these old classes were retrofitted to implement appropriate interfaces.

Answer (score 1):

> without "get" in its name

In addition to the other answers, this is a small nit - if the variable is a boolean, one should use "is" rather than "get".